# TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent is not waiting for child task

Tags: c#, async-await

According to MSDN:

> You can use the AttachedToParent option to express structured task
>   parallelism, because the parent task implicitly waits for all child
>   tasks to finish.

So I have this code:

```
public async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    var childTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    },TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

    return 1;
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var task = GetIntAsync();
    var result = await task;
    var time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    return View();  
}
```

I would like to know why the time is 0 and not 1000.

Comment: You should never use `StartNew()` with `async` methods, because it doesn't support them well. Instead, you should use `Task.Run()` (although that doesn't support `AttachedToParent`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code that uses the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) does not normally use `AttachedToParent`. `AttachedToParent` was part of the design of the Task Parallel Library (TPL). Both the TPL and TAP share the same `Task` type, but there are many TPL members that should be avoided in TAP code.

In TAP, you can support the notion of "parent" and "child" async methods by having the "parent" async method `await` the task returned from the "child" async method:

```
public async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
  var childTask = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    ...
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    ...
  });
  ...

  await childTask;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: What if you have an unbounded numbers of child tasks? Like listening for tcp clients and creating a new task for each of them. It doesn't make sense to store all those tasks in a collection. Otherwise you would need to create another task just to remove finished tasks to avoid the collection to explode; very ugly solution.

Comment: @drowa: Socket connections are independent, so there's no natural parent/child relationship there. Usually if you have a situation where there's a task you want to act as "parent" with a dynamic number of "children", that indicates that the underlying abstraction is actually a *stream*. Streams are more naturally handled with a stream-based approach, such as Rx or TPL Dataflow (both of which interoperate nicely with `async`).

Comment: @Stephan Cleary: The problem is that a task is usually, if not always, executed by background threads. For example, I'm implementing a Windows service which listens TCP clients. The service creates a task for each client. How could we make sure the client tasks will terminate nicely when the service is stopping? Note, like in the question here, both types of task, listening (parent) and client (child), are implemented with `async` delegates.

Comment: @drowa: The statement `a task is usually, if not always, executed by background threads` is incorrect. Tasks represent a future event completing. While it's *possible* that they could represent work done on the thread pool (`Task.Run`), the vast majority of tasks represent I/O-bound work and do not "run" anywhere. To implement cooperative shutdown, use `CancellationToken`s.

Comment: @Stephan Cleary: I know how to use `CancellationToken` to _initiate_ the shutdown of all tasks. The problem is that if I leave the `OnStop` method _before_ **all** tasks have terminated then I will give the `AppDomain` the opportunity to abort a background thread which happens to be executing a task. In this case, the task will be interrupted abruptly. This problem is easy to reproduce and it happens all the time on my tests. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how `CancellationToken` could help me on this.

Comment: @drowa: Yes, you'd have to (synchronously) wait for the tasks to complete before returning from `OnStop`.

Comment: @Stephan Cleary: So we're back to my initial question.

Comment: @drowa: In that situation, there's no reason you couldn't use a list of tasks.

Comment: @Stephan Cleary: I will use a list. But my point is that it would be cleaner if I could use `AttachedToParent`. I suspect it would be more efficient too, since it seems this feature is implemented internally by a simple counter. Another thing that seems natural for me would be the ability to create "foreground" tasks that wouldn't be interrupted by the `AppDomain` during its unloading. Anyway, thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Stephan Cleary: I added a solution for a "parent" with dynamic number of "children", which uses a single task instead of using a list of tasks. The solution is simple but not obvious, that's why I think it was worth sharing. It avoids problems we might encounter when using a list of tasks with unbounded number of short-lived children, which is not an uncommon scenario. Btw, the solution doesn't require a parent/children relationship. It could be used whenever you have an unbounded number of short-lived tasks.

Comment: @StephenCleary how you use await keyword in Task.Run(() =>{...});  ? 

(without async keyword)

Comment: @RamilAliyev007: Easy, I just forgot to type it! :D

Answer (score 5):

AttachedToParent only attaches to tasks that are scheduled. The Task returned by your async method is not scheduled, but rather comes (implicitly) from a TaskCompletionSource

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution that would work for a dynamic number of child tasks.

Using a list would be, in general, naive.

```
public async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    var childTasks = new List<Task>();

    while (...)
    {
        ...
        childTasks.Add(Task.Run(...));
        ...
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(childTasks);

    return 1;
}
```

For example, if the child tasks are short lived and, new ones are created rapidly and unboundedly, then the list would overflow.

Instead, we can use just one task.

```
public async Task<int> GetIntAsync()
{
    var childrenTask = Task.WhenAll();

    while (...)
    {
        ...
        childrenTask = Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(...), childrenTask);
        ...
    }

    await childrenTask;

    return 1;
}
```

Note this is a linked list of tasks which shrinks as soon as a task completes.