# Task hierarchy example not working as expected

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I am starting using Tasks in C#.
I am trying to execute this code.

```
    private static void CreateSubtask() {

        Task<Int32[]> parent = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var results = new Int32[3];
            new Task(() => results[0] = 0,
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
            new Task(() => results[1] = 1,
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
            new Task(() => results[2] = 2,
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).Start();
            return results;
        });
        var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(
           parentTask =>
           {
               foreach (int i in parentTask.Result)
                   Console.WriteLine(i);
           });
        finalTask.Wait();
    }
```

The `finalTask` runs only after the parent `Task` is finished, and the parent `Task` finishes when all three children are finished. You can use this to create quite complex `Task` hierarchies that will go through all the steps you specified.

What I got from the execution instead is three lines saying:

```
0
0
0
```

I was expecting them to be

```
0
1
2
```

Am I right?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Task Parallel Library, but I guess that the three tasks you create within your task `parent` haven't run yet at the time you are reading from `parent`'s result. It seems that you wait for `parent` to finish, but not for the three tasks created insinde `parent`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent is not waiting for child task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150448/taskcreationoptions-attachedtoparent-is-not-waiting-for-child-task)

Comment: I ran your code and I get 0 1 2 which is what I would expect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Task.Run` with the parent task suppresses the effect of `AttachedToParent` on the child task:

[Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) by Stephen Toub.

Use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead.

Comment: From the linked article: "[Task.Run] should simply be thought of as a quick way to use Task.Factory.StartNew". Further down in the article, it then elaborates that the parameters passed to the underlying StartNew include TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your `parent` task completes when it finishes *starting* the other three tasks, not when the other three tasks are *finished*.

Instead you can use `Task.WhenAll` to create a task that will be completed when all of the other tasks are themselves completed.

Another change to make your program more idiomatic task code is to have each inner task return their own value, rather than mutating some shared state, simply because dealing with shared state can be harder to reason about in a multithreaded environment.

```
var parent = Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => 0),
    Task.Run(() => 1),
    Task.Run(() => 2));
var finalTask = parent.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        foreach (int n in t.Result)
            Console.WriteLine(n);
    });
finalTask.Wait();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only starting your three sub tasks, but not waiting for them to finish. Adapt it like this, for example:

```
            var task1 = new Task(() => results[0] = 0,
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            var task2 = new Task(() => results[1] = 1,
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            var task3 = new Task(() => results[2] = 2,
                TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            task1.Start();
            task2.Start();
            task3.Start();

            task1.Wait();
            task2.Wait();
            task3.Wait();
```

Also note that with your current code, it is still possible to show `0 1 2` (not `1 2 3` by the way), as it is not determined when the subtasks are running / finishing. This might also be dependent on your build configuration (debug / release).

Comment: `AttachedToParent` normally makes the parent wait for its children. The question is, why doesn't it here?